# blazor ILoggerProvider how to get username? on API project

Tags: c#, api, authentication, logging, blazor

i want to build some logger provider
and have option to get username in it
how to do that?

i use some external OIDC
so in api i have only

```
 builder.Services
.AddAuthentication("Bearer")
.AddJwtBearer("Bearer", options =>
{
    options.Authority = "https://xxxx/auth/realms/dev";
    options.TokenValidationParameters.ValidateAudience = false;
});
```

so now

```
builder.Services.AddScoped<ILoggerProvider,DbLoggerProvider>();
```

and if i want to get in ctor

```
 public DbLoggerProvider(IOptions<DbLoggerProvider> options, AuthenticationStateProvider asp)
```

then it crash on build with message that

```
 System.AggregateException
 Message=Some services are not able to be constructed
 Source=Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection
 StackTrace:
 at
 Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider. .ctor(ICollection`1 serviceDescriptors, ServiceProviderOptions options)
at 
Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollection 
ContainerBuilderExtensions.BuildServiceProvider 
(IServiceCollection services, ServiceProviderOptions options)
at Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostApplicationBuilder.Build()
at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder.WebApplicationBuilder.Build()
at Program.<Main>$(String[] args) in D:\x\Server\Program.cs:line 
153
This exception was originally thrown at this call stack:
[External Code]
Inner Exception 1:
InvalidOperationException: Error while validating the service 
descriptor 'ServiceType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.IHostApplicationLifetime Lifetime: Singleton ImplementationType: Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.ApplicationLifetime': Unable to resolve service for type 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization.AuthenticationStateProvider' while attempting to activate 'x.Server.Core.Providers.DbLoggerProvider'.
Inner Exception 2:
InvalidOperationException: Unable to resolve service for type 
'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Authorization. 
AuthenticationStateProvider' while attempting to activate 
'x.Server.Core.Providers.DbLoggerProvider'.
```

in `controllers` i get username like

```
  string login = User.Claims.Where(p => p.Type == "preferred_username").First().Value;
```

how can i have this login in loggerprovider?
how controller is getting this user object if nor from  `AuthenticationStateProvider`  ?

thanks and regards

Comment: Please post the full error message.

Comment: ok i updated sorry :)